# Phpstorm zen coding: insert <?php ?> tag

Tags: phpstorm, emmet

Is there a built-in zen coding shortcut in PhpStorm to insert a `<?php ?>` tag? If not, how would I go about setting one?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

No there is not, You can set it by Going to File -> Settings -> -- IDE Settings -- -> Live Templates -> Add And using the following values:-

> Abbreviation: php
>   Group: user
>   Template Text: `<?php $END$ ?>`
>   Context: Check HTML

Comment: Right. I was looking for "clips", obviously it is live templates in phpstorm. Thank you.

Comment: Template text should be: `<?php $END$ ?>`

Comment: Is there a way to assign a keyboard shortcut to specific live template? So, for instance ctrl+p would type <?php $END$ ?>.

Comment: I recommend to use this settings instead (type "<?" and press "SPACE"): http://magicento.com/assets/img/PHPBlock_live_template.jpg

Comment: #For Mac User: In phpstorm10 on mac the right path is PhpStorm->Preferences->Editor->Live Templates, click on the PHP and add new Live Template. Thanks to @Salman Abbas

Comment: awesome - but the fastest abbreviation could be just `<` then tab.

Answer (score 14):

In PhpStorm2016.1 must change Applicable in Value to HTML .

Go to File -> Setting -> Editor -> Code Style -> Live Templates 
On right sidebar click on "+" then : 
Abbreviation : (for example) p
Template text : 
Applicatin :change the value to HTMLl like befor
then click on ok .

[image]

Comment: Live Templates isn't in Code Style (at least in 2018 version) it's beneath it, but otherwise this helped me for more recent versions, thanks.

Comment: Thank you!Excellent answer!

Comment: Great answer, the screenshot helped a lot!

Answer (score 9):

In newer versions of PhpStorm(2019.* or higher) adding the shortcut is a little bit different.

First go to `File -> Settings` (or simply press `CTRL + ALT + S`). Open  `Editor` tab and find `Live Templates` tab. Select PHP and click small blue plus icon at the right sidebar, select live template and:

1. Type shortcut on `Abbreviation` input.
2. Type `<?php $END$ ?>` on `template text` area.
3. Define applicable context like php and html.
4. If you want to expand with another key instead tab, you must define another expand key.

Click `Apply` and `OK` buttons. That's it.

Answer (score 3):

Go to

```
File --> Settings --> Search & click Live Templates
```

Click + button on the right side
then click Live Template

lastly input following:

```
Abbreviation: PHP
Template Text: <?php $END$ ?>
Context: Check HTML
```

Click Apply then OK

Now type php and press tab in a php file

```
 PHP tag (<?PHP ?>) will automatically generated
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set it by going to **File -> Settings -> -- IDE Settings -- -> Live Templates**

and then input

```
Abbreviation: php
Group: user
Template Text: php $END$ ?>
Context:
Check HTML
```